# Integer promotion example in C

Tags: c, integer-promotion

```
void foo(void) {
    unsigned int a = 6;
    int b = -20;

    if (a+b > a) {
        printf("> a");
    } else {
        printf("< a");
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what is going on with the integer promotion example above. I know that for `a = 6` and `b = -20` the output should be `> a` due to `b` being promoted to `unsigned int`. However, the output goes to `< a` if I assign `b = -5`. Shouldn't the output be the same in this case as well since the value `b = -5` is also promoted to an `unsigned int`?

Comment: This FAQ has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this has to do with the method in which the signed value is converted to unsigned.

Section 6.3.1.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding conversions of signed and unsigned integers dictates how this occurs:

> *2* Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.<sup>60)</sup>
>
> ...
>
> 60) The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.

In your example with `b` equal to -20, when it is converted to unsigned  `UINT_MAX + 1` is added to the value, so the converted value is `UINT_MAX - 19`.  When you then add the value of `a` (6), you get `UINT_MAX - 13`.  This value is larger than `a`, so `"> a"` is printed.

If you set `b` equal to -5, the converted value is `UINT_MAX - 4`.  Adding 6 to this gives you `UINT_MAX + 2`.  Since math on `unsigned int` values occurs modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`, the actual result is 1.  This is less than 6, so `"< a"` is printed.

Also, what is happening here is not integer promotion but **integer conversion**.  Promotion happens first if any integer type in an expression has a rank less than `int`.  That is not the case here.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you!

Comment: What does that footnote mean, exactly? I don't understand what distinction it makes and Google doesn't help either